# JS: Iterate through an object's children objects, check if a < b, parse by child object's substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, document.write

NOTE: If you're interested in helping me knock this one out, please see the additional notes I've added as comments below to see some additional progress I've made. Thanks!

I'm trying to create a simple program of sorts for referencing college football schedules and tracking wins, losses, and potential playoff participants based on their rank. I'm at my wits end trying to make a script that shows which teams have a higher rank than the team in question, of that subset checking which higher ranked teams have the substring "LOSS", and then document.write those teams to the declared div. I feel like, logically, I really understand the steps that should be happening, but being a real novice, I'm hitting a wall/mental block that (kinda embarrassingly) has persisted after several hours of testing, sifting through Stackoverflow, testing, Googling more, testing, etc.

I'm just not a good enough developer yet.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

(Date sets that I'm working with; only a subset of team children objects included to limit the amount of space taken up here:)

```
// Declare global team variable (leftover from another JS file utilizing the same data)

var teamSched;

// 2014 College Foootball Gamedays

var gameDays = {
week1: ["Thursday, August 28th",
"Friday, August 29th",
"Saturday, August 30th",
"Sunday, August 31st",
"Monday, September 1st"],
week2: ["Thursday, September 4th",
"Friday, September 5th",
"Saturday, September 6th"],
week3: ["Thursday, September 11th",
"Friday, September 12th",
"Saturday, September 13th",
"Sunday, September 14th"],
week4: ["Thursday, September 18th",
"Friday, September 19th",
"Saturday, September 20th"],
week5: ["Thursday, September 25th",
"Friday, September 26th",
"Saturday, September 27th"],
week6: ["Thursday, October 2nd",
"Friday, October 3rd",
"Saturday, October 4th"],
week7: ["Thursday, October 9th",
"Friday, October 10th",
"Saturday, October 11th",
"Sunday, October 12th"],
week8: ["Tuesday, October 14th",
"Thursday, October 16th",
"Friday, October 17th",
"Saturday, October 18th"],
week9: ["Tuesday, October 21st",
"Thursday, October 23rd",
"Friday, October 24th",
"Saturday, October 25th",
"Sunday, October 26th"],
week10: ["Thursday, October 30th",
"Friday, October 31st",
"Saturday, November 1st"],
week11: ["Tuesday, November 4th",
"Wednesday, November 5th",
"Thursday, November 6th",
"Friday, November 7th",
"Saturday, November 8th"],
week12: ["Tuesday, November 11th",
"Wednesday, November 12th",
"Thursday, November 13th",
"Friday, November 14th",
"Saturday, November 15th"],
week13: ["Tuesday, November 18th",
"Wednesday, November 19th",
"Thursday, November 20th",
"Friday, November 21st",
"Saturday, November 22nd",
"Sunday, November 23rd"],
week14: ["Tuesday, November 25th",
"Thursday, November 27th",
"Friday, November 28th",
"Saturday, November 29th"],
week15: ["Thursday, December 4th",
"Saturday, December 6th"],
week16: ["Saturday, December 13th"]
}

// Individual Top 24 Team Objects

// #1:

teams = {

    fsu: {
    rank: 1,
    conf: "ACC",
    sched: 
        [gameDays.week1[2] + " <b>vs Oklahoma State</b>",
        gameDays.week2[2] + " <b>vs Citadel</b>",
        gameDays.week4[2] + " <b>vs #16 Clemson</b>",
        gameDays.week5[2] + " <b>at North Carolina State</b>",
        gameDays.week6[2] + " <b>vs Wake Forest</b>",
        gameDays.week7[2] + " <b>at Syracuse</b>",
        gameDays.week8[3] + " <b>vs #17 Notre Dame</b>",
        gameDays.week10[0] + " <b>at Louisville</b>",
        gameDays.week11[4] + " <b>vs Virginia</b>",
        gameDays.week12[4] + " <b>at Miami</b>",
        gameDays.week13[4] + " <b>vs Boston College</b>",
        gameDays.week14[3] + " <b>vs Florida</b>"]
},

// #2:

    bama: {
    rank: 2,
    conf: "SEC",
    sched: 
        [gameDays.week1[2] + " <b>vs West Virginia</b>",
        gameDays.week2[2] + " <b>vs Florida International</b>",
        gameDays.week3[2] + " <b>vs Southern Mississippi</b>",
        gameDays.week4[2] + " <b>vs Florida</b>",
        gameDays.week6[2] + " <b>at #18 Ole Miss</b>",
        gameDays.week7[2] + " <b>at Arkansas</b>",
        gameDays.week8[3] + " <b>vs #21 Texas A&M</b>",
        gameDays.week9[3] + " <b>at Tennessee</b>",
        gameDays.week11[4] + " <b>at #13 LSU</b>",
        gameDays.week12[4] + " <b>vs Mississippi State</b>",
        gameDays.week13[4] + " <b>vs Western Carolina</b>",
        gameDays.week14[3] + " <b>vs #6 Auburn</b>"]
},

usce: {
    rank: 9,
    conf: "SEC",
    sched: 
        [gameDays.week1[0] + " <b>vs #21 Texas A&M, LOSS (28-52)</b>",
        gameDays.week2[2] + " <b>vs East Carolina</b>",
        gameDays.week3[2] + " <b>vs #12 Georgia</b>",
        gameDays.week4[2] + " <b>at Vanderbilt</b>",
        gameDays.week5[2] + " <b>vs #24 Missouri</b>",
        gameDays.week6[2] + " <b>at Kentucky</b>",
        gameDays.week8[3] + " <b>vs Furman</b>",
        gameDays.week9[3] + " <b>at #6 Auburn</b>",
        gameDays.week10[2] + " <b>vs Tennessee</b>",
        gameDays.week12[4] + " <b>at Florida</b>",
        gameDays.week13[4] + " <b>vs South Alabama</b>",
        gameDays.week14[3] + " <b>at #16 Clemson</b>"]
},

texasam: {
    rank: 21,
    conf: "SEC",
    sched: 
        [gameDays.week1[0] + " <b>at #9 South Carolina, WIN (52-28)</b>",
        gameDays.week2[2] + " <b>vs Lamar</b>",
        gameDays.week3[2] + " <b>vs Rice</b>",
        gameDays.week4[2] + " <b>at SMU</b>",
        gameDays.week5[2] + " <b>vs Arkansas</b>",
        gameDays.week6[2] + " <b>at Mississippi State</b>",
        gameDays.week7[2] + " <b>at #18 Ole Miss</b>",
        gameDays.week8[3] + " <b>at #2 Alabama</b>",
        gameDays.week10[2] + " <b>vs UL-Monroe</b>",
        gameDays.week11[4] + " <b>at #6 Auburn</b>",
        gameDays.week12[4] + " <b>vs #24 Missouri</b>",
        gameDays.week14[1] + " <b>vs #13 LSU</b>"]
}
```

Step by Step, as best as I can outline it:

1) Parse URL (i.e. "../folder/texasam.html") to obtain desired string, and then store that team name in a variable for referencing later (CODE WORKING)

```
function parseURL() {
  var match = window.location.href.match(/(\w+).html$/);
  if (match) {
    return match[1];
  }
  return null;
}

var teamElim = parseURL();
```

2) Set variable in Step 1 to hold their rank value for referencing later (CODE WORKING)

```
var teamRank = teams[teamElim].rank;
```

3) Iterate over a specific element (an array) that is nested in an object's child object (CODE NOT WORKING)

```
function iterateTeams() {
    for (var team in teams) {
            console.log(team);
        }
}

iterateTeams()
```

So, this has *some* promise at least, because I'm able to actually iterate over each "team" value in the "teams" object. I, for the life of me though, cannot figure out how to reach further into the children object's elements, specifically the .rank (or the .sched keys later) without getting a return value of "undefined".

4) Here, I need to check each child object's .rank key value to create a subset of all teams with a rank value that is greater than the "teamRank" variable, which in this case is "21". (NO WORKING CODE, JUST THEORIZING)

This is where I really get lost. I think that this should look, more or less, something like this, perhaps?:

```
function rankCheck(a, b) {
    var finalRankSubset = (a < b);
    if(teamRank.valueOf() < newRankSubset.valueOf()); {
        //RIGHT HERE I AM ESPECIALLY LOST
    }
}
```

I have two questions/problems here:

a) How do I store that newRankSubset value (perhaps I need to find a way to dynamically create an array?)?

b) How do I then parse through that later? Still, I feel like my biggest issue is that, since I can get "deep" enough into the children object's elements, I can't try to test how to properly call down, parse, and then store that data for later use.

5) Now, I need to iterate through this new subset of data that contains all teams that are ranked above "21", and then check the strings stored in .sched keys for the substring "LOSS". (NO CODE AT ALL)

Here, I'm pretty much asking the same question as above in "b": How do I take the captured subset data of all teams ranked above "texasam" (21), and then check their .sched keys for the substring "LOSS"?

Given that I'm already so lost above, I'm not even sure where to begin here and would truly appreciate any assistance.

6) Finally, I need to insert all of that into a div, in this case, the div id "threatText". I think the below code will work, except I'm about 99.999% sure that I'll need to change the actual document.write() value(s) for it to do so:

```
function deliverTeams() {
    document.getElementById('threatText').innerHTML;
    document.write(teams[teamSched].sched.join("<br>"));
}
```

I came pretty close to making [my other project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573365/dynamically-selecting-specific-object-and-key-value-to-iterate-over-doc-write-t) with this data work before having to reach out for help (and thanks a ton for the help I did receive!), and though I know exactly what I want to do here, and, in some places, I think that I understand at least a portion of the code needed to do it, I think I'm a lot further away than my previous project.

I hope this doesn't come across as me asking for others to just write my code for me, as that's not my desire and I'm more than happy feel my way through this with anybody willing to offer guidance. I truly have made my best effort to nail this one down myself, I'm just, unfortunately, too green of a programmer to pull this one off by myself at the moment.

Thank you very much for any help and guidance you're willing to provide!

Comment: So I've continued to make very minor progress, as I've finally figured out how to access the three keys of the children objects:

function cycleTeams () {
 var teamKeys = Object.keys(teams[team]);
  console.log(teamKeys);
}

(console.log is called just to test)

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to pair it with the iteration over team in the "teams" object. If I can pair the two, I think that'll be significant progress.

Comment: Another update:

I think I've figured out how to gain access to the keys for each object by making some changes to my iterateTeams function:

function iterateTeams() {
 var teamArray = [];
 for (var team in teams) {
   var teamKey = teams[team];
      teamArray.push(teamKey);
    }
    console.log(teamArray[0]);
}

So, now, with the "teamArray[0]" variable, I get this in the console:

Object {rank: 1, conf: "ACC", sched: Array[12]}

Which allows me to access each key in the expected ".rank", ".key", etc.

Still trying to figure out the rest though...

Comment: please split up your question into several questions. also please remove the steps that are working and formulate one question in each post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue when iterating through the teams (step 3) is that the [*for..in statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/for...in) `for (var team in teams)` iterates through the property names of an object, not through the properties and their instances like you probably are assuming. Therefore, you have to get the property value:

```
function iterateTeams() {

    for ( var teamName in teams ) {       

            var team = teams[teamName];
            console.log('TEAM: ' + teamName);

            ...
```

Now that you have a reference to the team, you can access its `sched` array:

```
            ...

            for ( var i = 0; i < team.sched.length; i++ ) {
                var schedDay = team.sched[i];
                console.log(schedDay);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton dreamlab, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.

Looking at the output in the console for the code you gave me, it looks to me like I have 2 questions:

1) How do I parse for just the teams whose rank is greater than the rank of the team I'm comparing against (parseURL() value)?

2) How do I then, from that subset of data, obtain and then deliver to the designated div in the page's HTML those games that contain the substring "LOSS"?

Please let me know if I should rework my main post if that's where you'd prefer the questions to be asked; I'd be happy to do it!

Thanks again!

Comment: As an aside, I'm about to call it night as I need to be up early in the AM, but I'll be happy to rework my entire post if needed once I'm back in front of my machine. I'll also be giving it a shot myself to tinker and try and write the necessary code to deliver on my two questions above, and I haven't heard back from you by that time, I'll be updating with the progress I've made.

Thanks again, so much!

Comment: I'll just posts some separate questions and see if that makes it easier, as I'm 100% stumped right now.

Thanks again!

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for. Was wasting my time when only a string was being logged in my `console.log()` statements, yet I knew I had child objects. Thanks!